# How to get a master detail query by loopback?

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, loopback

I have Company and Product `model` with has many relation from company to product model. 
how to make a Get method to get `company name` or `ID` returns company information with all related products.

something like fallowing object:

```
 [{
        "C_name": "tatli",
        "address": "TR-IS- aktepe",
        "tel": "123456789",
        "id": "5a18772e61b6370e4c713b44",
      [{
    "P_Code": "123456",
    "P_name": "screw",
    "QTY": 30,
    "id": "5a1878af61b6370e4c713b46",
    "compny_id": "5a18772e61b6370e4c713b44"
  },
  {
    "P_Code": "123457",
    "P_name": "Bead",
    "QTY": 33,
    "id": "5a1878af61b6370e4c713b47",
    "compny_id": "5a18772e61b6370e4c713b44"
  }]
    }]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope you have provided the Relation properly in the model of Company .
If not just look at the following  [link](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Creating-model-relations.html) and Create the relation . In this case the relation will be a belongs to .

> Product Belongs to a Company

In order to query the related results you have two ways .

- Including it the default model of Company . So that loopback's default get will return you all the rows.
  Like

**company.json model file**

```
  "relations": { // make sure the name of product model and foreign key is correct
    "product": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "product",
      "foreignKey": "productId"
    }
  },

 "scope": {
    "include": "product"
  },
```

- Second way is to write it in a remote method.

> ```
> Company.getPrefs = function(id, cb) {
>     Company.find({
>     where: {        
>     },
>     include: [{relation: 'Product'}]
> };
> ```

Comment: How to make it for master detail detail, for example `compony -< products -< product info`?

Comment: @RSA include it inside scope of the include or add it to the included model

Comment: I think second way to implementation is much better than adding scope in JSON. Am i had to make hasManyThrough relation with company and product info Through products?

Comment: Tnx, I got solution by your comment.